# clang-tidy cannot find C standard library headers files like <math.h>, <string.h>, etc

Tags: c, clang-tidy, vim-ale

I am using `clang-tidy` as a linter for `ALE` in `Vim`.
I am running on a `Windows 10` machine.
Everything works as expected but every time there is some header file from the standard library like `<math.h>` or `<string.h>` I got a `file not found error`.
When this happens, nothing is lint any longer (I tried to remove a `{` in the code just for test but such an error is not lint).
I have no problems with other `.h` files.

I am pretty sure that I need to pass some option to `clang-tidy` but I cannot figure out which one.
If it may help, here is my `ALEInfo`

```
 Current Filetype: c
Available Linters: ['cc', 'ccls', 'clangd', 'clangtidy', 'cppcheck', 'cquery', 'flawfinder']
   Linter Aliases:
'cc' -> ['gcc', 'clang']
  Enabled Linters: ['clangtidy']
  Ignored Linters: []
 Suggested Fixers: 
  'astyle' - Fix C/C++ with astyle.
  'clang-format' - Fix C/C++ and cuda files with clang-format.
  'clangtidy' - Fix C/C++ and ObjectiveC files with clang-tidy.
  'remove_trailing_lines' - Remove all blank lines at the end of a file.
  'trim_whitespace' - Remove all trailing whitespace characters at the end of every line.
  'uncrustify' - Fix C, C++, C#, ObjectiveC, ObjectiveC++, D, Java, Pawn, and VALA files with uncrustify.
 Linter Variables:

let g:ale_c_always_make = 0
let g:ale_c_build_dir = ''
let g:ale_c_build_dir_names = ['build', 'bin']
let g:ale_c_clangtidy_checks = ['*']
let g:ale_c_clangtidy_executable = 'clang-tidy'
let g:ale_c_clangtidy_extra_options = ''
let g:ale_c_clangtidy_options = ''
let g:ale_c_parse_compile_commands = 1
let g:ale_c_parse_makefile = 0
 Global Variables:

let g:ale_cache_executable_check_failures = v:null
let g:ale_change_sign_column_color = 0
let g:ale_command_wrapper = ''
let g:ale_completion_delay = v:null
let g:ale_completion_enabled = 0
let g:ale_completion_max_suggestions = v:null
let g:ale_disable_lsp = 0
let g:ale_echo_cursor = 1
let g:ale_echo_msg_error_str = 'Error'
let g:ale_echo_msg_format = '%code: %%s'
let g:ale_echo_msg_info_str = 'Info'
let g:ale_echo_msg_warning_str = 'Warning'
let g:ale_enabled = 1
let g:ale_fix_on_save = 0
let g:ale_fixers = {'c': ['astyle', 'clangtidy', 'remove_trailing_lines', 'trim_whitespace']}
let g:ale_history_enabled = 1
let g:ale_history_log_output = 1
let g:ale_keep_list_window_open = 0
let g:ale_lint_delay = 200
let g:ale_lint_on_enter = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_filetype_changed = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_insert_leave = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_save = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_text_changed = 'normal'
let g:ale_linter_aliases = {}
let g:ale_linters = {'c': ['clangtidy'], 'python': ['flake8']}
let g:ale_linters_explicit = 0
let g:ale_linters_ignore = {}
let g:ale_list_vertical = 0
let g:ale_list_window_size = 10
let g:ale_loclist_msg_format = '%code: %%s'
let g:ale_max_buffer_history_size = 20
let g:ale_max_signs = -1
let g:ale_maximum_file_size = v:null
let g:ale_open_list = 0
let g:ale_pattern_options = v:null
let g:ale_pattern_options_enabled = v:null
let g:ale_root = {}
let g:ale_set_balloons = 0
let g:ale_set_highlights = 1
let g:ale_set_loclist = 1
let g:ale_set_quickfix = 0
let g:ale_set_signs = 1
let g:ale_sign_column_always = 0
let g:ale_sign_error = '>>'
let g:ale_sign_info = '--'
let g:ale_sign_offset = 1000000
let g:ale_sign_style_error = '>>'
let g:ale_sign_style_warning = '--'
let g:ale_sign_warning = '--'
let g:ale_sign_highlight_linenrs = 0
let g:ale_statusline_format = v:null
let g:ale_type_map = {}
let g:ale_use_global_executables = v:null
let g:ale_virtualtext_cursor = 0
let g:ale_warn_about_trailing_blank_lines = 1
let g:ale_warn_about_trailing_whitespace = 1
```

Comment: Isn't it C++ where those headers are deprecated, not C?

Comment: `<math.h>` and `<string.h>` are in no way deprecated in C.

Comment: So do you believe you are programming in C, or in C++?  (Or did someone tell you they were the same language?)

Comment: I am sorry. I am going to tweak my question. I believed they were deprecated for C as well.